# Why is $\operatorname{mod}(\operatorname{arcsinh}(x),x) = \operatorname{arcsinh}(x)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

So I was messing around with functions in desmos and I found out that $y=\operatorname{mod}(\operatorname{arcsinh}(x),x)$ and $y=\operatorname{arcsinh}(x)$ have the same graph.

Could someone tell me why this is the case?

Comment: If $x\neq 0$, then, by definition, $$
\bmod\! (\sinh ^{ - 1} (x),x) = \sinh ^{ - 1} (x) - x\left\lfloor {\frac{{\sinh ^{ - 1} (x)}}{x}} \right\rfloor  = \sinh ^{ - 1} (x)
$$ since $0<\frac{{\sinh ^{ - 1} (x)}}{x}<1$ for $x \neq 0$. For $x=0$, it is obvious.

Answer (score 1):

First, we can observe that
$$
x > \operatorname{arcsinh} x
$$
when $x$ is positive. Because of this, the remainder of $\frac{\operatorname{arcsinh} x}{x}$ is simply $\operatorname{arcsinh} x$. On a graph, you can see this fact play out, as there line is a jump discontinuity for $\operatorname{mod}(a, b)$ whenever $a = b$, and thus the line essentially repeats its upward trend when $a > b$.

Second, we can see
$$
x < \operatorname{arcsinh} x
$$
when $x$ is negative. Because $x$ and $\operatorname{archsinh} x$ are both of the same sign, the definition of $\operatorname{mod}(a, b) = \operatorname{rem}(a, b)$ is valid here. the remainder of $\frac{\operatorname{arcsinh} x}{x}$ is $\operatorname{arcsinh} x$.

Lastly, in the case that $x = 0$, we know that $x = \operatorname{arcsinh} x = 0$. Because $\operatorname{arcsinh} x$ and $x$ are equal, their remainder is 0.

By piecing this all together, it can be verified that $\operatorname{mod}(\operatorname{arcsinh} x, x) = \operatorname{arcsinh} x$.

Excellent question, by the way. This is my first time answering a question on Math StackExchange, so please let me know if you have any further questions in case I didn't explain something well enough.

Comment: Thank you for your insightful answer, William. To be honest, I don't know much about the mod and rem functions. Do you know of any resources that can help me learn more about them?

Comment: @ChonkyCat No problem, your question was a good one. Whilst Wikipedia often isn't great as a source, I think it can help you learn more about the function as a whole. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation. In fact, there are multiple different implementations of the modulo operation; Desmos just has one of them! I think that this article on Wikipedia about Euclidean division https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division could be of help about learning about remainders. YouTube is also a great resource. Here's the first video that pops up: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Eg6CTCu8iio